# Как интерпретировать последовательность байтов в виде int'a?

Tags: c++

Если имеется char * bytes длины 4, то можно ли bytes прикастовать к int'y с учетом отрицательности числа? Может что-то типа reinterpret_cast(bytes)?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [`int* integer = reinterpret_cast<int*>(bytes);`](https://ideone.com/OAQDFA)?

Comment: И правда! Спасибо большое.

Comment: @ヒミコ, в зависимости от платформы.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *bytes;
...
int a;
std::memcpy(&a, bytes, sizeof a);
```